# OpenLayers and Ionic 3 | tileLoadFunction not working

Tags: openlayers, typescript

I am building a simple map app with the Ionic 3 framework.  I am using OpenLayers 4.0.2 as the map api.

It has been going great until I tried implementing a custom tileLoadFunction for the basemap tile layer used in the app.  In my case, I am attempting to get tiles from an IndexedDB.

```
 tileLoadFunction: function(tile, src) {
     let imageTile = tile as ol.ImageTile;
     let img = imageTile.getImage() as HTMLImageElement;
     let tileCoord = imageTile.getTileCoord();
     tileCoord[2] = -tileCoord[2] - 1;
     self.mapDataService.getBasemapTile(tileCoord).then(b64 => {
         if (b64) {
             img.setAttribute('src', b64);
         } else {
             img.setAttribute('src', src);
             self.mapDataService.cacheBasemapTile(tileCoord,src);
         }
     });
 }
```

This is fairly common requirement, and I have seen dozen of implementations online - but not in TypeScript...  I can't just do `tile.getImage().src = b64;` or else I get complile errors.  So I cast to ol.ImageTile and HTMLImageElement.

I am 100% positive that the images returned by b64 or src variables are valid images. But the basemap tile is always blank???  Is there a better way to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: I have similar problem.
Mine use openstreetmap (OSM tiles) at parent and use another type of layer.
I used custom tileLoadFunction NOT on parent, but seems blank when child layer are not calling proper tileLoadFn. Idk why